# Working with overflows

Tags: html, css

In my body I have this. I don't want my pages to have a horizontal scroll so i put overflow-x: hidden.

```
  html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Gravity-Regular';
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Now the problem lies on my homepage where I have an animated effect and the css on this effect are as follows.

```
 .cbp-so-scroller {
    overflow: hidden;
 }
.cbp-so-side {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 48px 4%;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 192px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}
```

So as you can see they change overflow to hidden. When i takes away overflow-x: hidden from my html/body, the animations work fine, but I want to leave the overflow setting there. Is there anyway to configure these overflows? I've tried using :not(.cbp-so-scroller) but to no luck.

Comment: So I was playing around and I put overflow-x: hidden in just the body and not in the html too and it works. I have no idea why that is though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate `div` for your animations and make that `div` positioned fixed or absolute, give `overflow: hidden`, based on your requirement and do it this way:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.querySelector("#main").innerHTML = "Hello, World! ".repeat(100);
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector("#anim-mask span").classList.add("anim");
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.querySelector("#anim-mask span").classList.remove("anim");
    }, 2000);
  }, 500);
};
```

```css
#anim-mask {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#anim-mask span {
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  -webkit-transition: all 5s;
  -moz-transition: all 5s;
  -ms-transition: all 5s;
  -o-transition: all 5s;
  transition: all 5s;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

#anim-mask span.anim {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1525px;
}
```

```html
<div id="anim-mask"><span>Animated</span></div>
<div id="main">
  Main content flow.
</div>
```